# Existe alguma API que liste estados e cidades?

Tags: json, api

Estive buscando por alguma API json que liste os estados de um determinado país, ou cidades de um determinado estado, procurei esta funcionalidade por várias APIs do Google Maps mas não encontrei nada que fosse exatamente para isto.

Eu não quero usar uma DB com uma lista de estados e cidades porque acredito que falta flexibilidade e é algo bastante pesado.

Obs: a necessidade é criar um combobox de países, estados e cidades, porém posso utilizar uma lista de países direto do banco de dados sem nenhum problema, mas caso haja uma API que disponibilize esta lista também é melhor ainda.

Há uma boa opção?

Comment: Já há boas respostas aqui sobre isto, em particular para cidades PT & BR. Isso serve-te ou queres cidades do mundo inteiro?

Comment: Sim, vou precisar de uma lista com todos os países, e em sequência fazer uma requisição da lista de estados, e cidades referente a cada estado.

Comment: Estive procurando por algum similar e achei [esse JSON no Github](https://gist.github.com/letanure/3012978) que pode ser útil.

Comment: Sei que é um pouco antigo, mas pode ajudar outros Use a API do IBGE para isso, fonte mais confiável é impossível.
Segue a documentação:
https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/docs/localidades

Comment: so pra constar, da pra usar a api do google maps também.

Comment: Não usar BD é complicado por ficar dependente de API de terceiros, eu já tenho um migrate para cidades e estados que utilizo em Laravel.
Para o seu caso a solução do IBGE citada acima seria a melhor opção.

Comment: Encontrei uma outra API com estados e municípios do Brasil que tem sido bem útil pra mim, é essa aqui: https://www.back4app.com/database/back4app/api-estados-cidades-brasil

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o serviço público [geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org/).

Esta página de exemplo mostra as chamadas ao serviço:

http://vikku.info/programming/geodata/geonames-get-country-state-city-hierarchy.htm

A função específica que você deseja utilizar é [Children](http://www.geonames.org/export/place-hierarchy.html#children), que retorna coleções de entidades-filhas de um dado `GeoNameID` - países de um continente, estados de um país, cidades de um estado e assim em diante.

O exemplo acima faz as seguintes chamadas:

1. Obtém uma lista de continentes

   http://www.geonames.org/childrenJSON?geonameId=6295630
2. Após a seleção de América do Sul (*GeoNameID* 6255150), obtém a lista de países

   http://www.geonames.org/childrenJSON?geonameId=6255150
3. Após a seleção de Brasil (*GeoNameID* 3469034), obtém a lista de estados

   http://www.geonames.org/childrenJSON?geonameId=3469034

O resultado final é uma lista similar ao exemplo abaixo:

```
{
"totalResultsCount":27,
"geonames":[
    {
    "geonameId":3665474,
    "toponymName":"Acre"
    },
    {
    "geonameId":3408096,
    "toponymName":"Alagoas"
    },
    {
    "geonameId":3407762,
    "toponymName":"Amapá"
    },
    [...]
```

Comment: Essa API falta algumas cidades, ao selecionar o estado de São Paulo, você não obtem algumas cidades como a Capital São Paulo, São Bernado do Campo e etc.

[Sâo Paulo](http://www.geonames.org/childrenJSON?geonameId=3448433)

Comment: não é que falta, a chamada da API limita os resultados