# Download Async Task C#

Tags: c#

Olá estou com a seguinte situação com esse função.
E esta dando essa rejeição

‘WebClient’ não contém uma definição para "DownloadDataTaskAsync" e não foi possível encontrar nenhum método de extensão "DownloadDataTaskAsync" que aceite um primeiro argumento do tipo ‘WebClient’ (você está se esquecendo de usar uma diretiva ou uma referência de assembly?

```
static async Task DownloadAsync(string sUrl, string sNomeArq)
    {
        Uri uUri = new Uri(sUrl);
        // cria uma instância de webclient
        using (WebClient cliente = new WebClient())
        {
            byte[] bytes;
            try
            {
                // Existe também o método DownloadDataAsync 
                bytes = await cliente.DownloadDataTaskAsync(uUri);
            }
            catch (WebException we)
            {
                return;
            }

            FileStream Stream = new FileStream(@"D:\temp\" + sNomeArq, FileMode.Create);

            //Escrevo arquivo no fluxo
            Stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            //Fecho fluxo pra finalmente salvar em disco
            Stream.Close();
        }
    }
```

Porem fiz com uma aplicação Console e deu certo da seguinte forma e deu certo. Oq esta errado alguém pode me ajudar ?

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> lt = new List<string>();
        lt.Clear();
        lt.Add("http://www.teste.com.br/atualizasgl/arquivos/7226B398B8ADDDCB5D64412B6FEEBB71.zip");
        lt.Add("http://www.teste.com.br/atualizasgl/arquivos/7BC630726516F5B9006DC21F98E77D94.zip ");
        lt.Add("http://www.teste.com.br/atualizasgl/arquivos/B9E3AF228E5543E8E045C38550B5D124.zip ");
        lt.Add("http://www.teste.com.br/atualizasgl/arquivos/2DE19CEE12378ADEC17FDAB3ECB57E92.zip ");

        foreach (string sLink in lt)
        {
            await DownloadAsync(sLink, "Arq" + lt.IndexOf(sLink) + ".zip");
        }
        //Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task DownloadAsync(string url, string sNomeArq)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        // cria uma instância de webclient
        using (WebClient cliente = new WebClient())
        {
            // OBTEM O CONTEÚDO DO ARQUIVO
            Console.WriteLine($"Downloading {uri.AbsoluteUri}");
            cliente.DownloadDataCompleted += Cliente_DownloadDataCompleted;
            cliente.DownloadProgressChanged += Cliente_DownloadProgressChanged;
            // faz o download da pagina e armazena em um array de bytes
            byte[] bytes;
            try
            {
                bytes = await cliente.DownloadDataTaskAsync(uri);
            }
            catch (WebException we)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(we.ToString());
                return;
            }


            //Crio o arquivo em disco e um fluxo
            FileStream Stream = new FileStream(@"D:\temp\" + sNomeArq, FileMode.Create);

            //Escrevo arquivo no fluxo
            Stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            //Fecho fluxo pra finalmente salvar em disco
            Stream.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

O método `DownloadDataTaskAsync` pertence à classe `System.Net.WebClient`:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloaddatataskasync?view=net-5.0

Precisa usar essa classe e seu código vai funcionar:

```
string url = "http://www.geonames.org/childrenJSON?geonameId=6255150";

// Não usei using, aqui o namespace completo:
using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    var  result = await wc.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);
    var json = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(result);
    
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

Pode ser visto funcionando aqui: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8GJdvh

Em tempo, peguei esse endpoint dessa outra resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/76649/57220

Answer (score 0):

Eu acredito que o erro seja porque você está esquecendo de importar alguma biblioteca do C#, como está dizendo em: `você está se esquecendo de usar uma diretiva ou uma referência de assembly?`, se você estiver usando o Visual Studio, basta apertar colocar cursor na linha onde está o erro e apertar `Ctrl` + `.`, e se o problema for realmente falta de importação de biblioteca, o Visual Studio irá dar a sugestão de importar a biblioteca